# Восстановление auto-renewable subscriptions на другом устройсте

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Есть необходимость внедрить auto-renewable подписку в приложении, в связи с чем возник вопрос касаемо ее восстановления.

Ситуация следующая: в приложении нет авторизации. Пользователь под apple id совершает покупку подписки. Далее устанавливает приложение на другое устройство под тем же apple id. Далее нажимает кнопку восстановления покупки.

Далее вопрос, как произвести восстановление купленной подписки? Достаточно ли будет использовать метод [restoreCompletedTransactions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions?preferredLanguage=occ) или нужно смотреть в сторону использования [restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1505992-restorecompletedtransactionswith?language=objc)?

Если должен использоваться второй метод, что должно выступать в роли параметра **username**? Использовать для этих целей [SKMutablePayment.applicationUsername](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skmutablepayment/1506088-applicationusername?language=objc)?

Comment: Достаточно restoreCompletedTransactions. For example, your application would use this to allow a user to unlock previously purchased content onto a new device.

Comment: Если пользователь не авторизован на устройстве, то iOS автоматически запросит у него авторизацию и под этим id восстановит покупку. Если авторизован под другим id, то можно будет переключиться. Это можно протестить.

Comment: Так Auto-Renewable же даже восстанавливать не нужно, насколько я помню. При запросе receipt'a сразу придут данные о подписке при таком же apple id

Comment: Я не уверен что restoreCompletedTransactions верно сообщает если вышел срок покупки (возможно кто то меня поправит). Верно было бы делать проверку чека, но она работает довольно странно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно использовать метод `SKPaymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()`. Все дело в том, что у Apple покупки типа auto-renewable subscription также неявно входят в категорию non-consumable. Поведение механизма восстановления покупок для auto-renewable subscription и non-consumable идентично.

Когда вы совершаете покупку такого типа, информация о ней заносится в reciept, который вы получаете со стора и `restoreCompletedTransactions()` способна вернуть такой reciept в приложения.

Кроме того, в документации явно указано:

> You call this method in one of the following situations:
>
> - To install purchases on additional devices
> - To restore purchases for an application that the user deleted and reinstalled

В свою очередь метод `restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername` используется только для покупок, которые были совершены с указанием `applicationUsername`. Такое имя пользователя может быть использовано, если вы реализуете аккаунт внутри приложения, под которым пользователь может заходить в приложение на разных устройствах и под разными apple Id. В случае с разными apple Id и одного аккаунта должна быть возможность совершать покупки в прилжении, независимо от apple id и зачислять их на один и тот же аккаунт приложения.